# Indexing structured dataset XML documents in Solr/lucene

Tags: xml, solr, lucene, dataimporthandler, structured-data

I am trying to use Solr to index a small dataset of XML Documents,
sample xml here:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<doc xmin = 0, xmax = 9.233174603174604>     
<title>John speech</title>
<description>shjshksjcjslkclsjk </description>
<uploaded_time>03/14/2010 08:44 PM</uploaded_time>
<likes>84906</likes>
<tier name="words">
<trans   xmin="0.0"  xmax="0.8325873015873018">silent</trans>
<trans   xmin="0.8325873015873018"   xmax="1.9564232192938984">Hi</trans>
<trans   xmin="1.9564232192938984"   xmax="3.874938884654082">I</trans>
<trans   xmin="3.874938884654082"    xmax="4.940780920965295">am</trans>
<trans   xmin="4.940780920965295"    xmax="6.495133890585815">John</trans>
:
:
</tier>
<doc>
```

Is this type of nested xml tags indexable by Solr?
I tried the DataImportHandler with [solrconfig.xml](https://gist.github.com/faridasabry/e7eead99c3913cb8971cd067fe8db2ab)! and this [xml-data-config.xml](https://gist.github.com/faridasabry/8d3bb9066bc9b784e11e3095e672ab21)! (not sure about its correctness still have no clear understanding of how to deal with nested xml especially for the undetermined tier length)

But trying to do the dataimport, I receive :

> Indexing ...
>   Requests: 0 , Fetched: 0 , Skipped: 0 , Processed: 0

and it is kept for a long time although my small dataset only contains few short files.

What I am missing??

Comment: Do you have these fields defined in schema.xml

Comment: no I thought according to [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler) that only dataconfig file will do the job.. so how to build this schema.xml

Comment: which version of solr been used? did you create any core...? how..?

Comment: solr 6.0  Yes I created a core using the command: bin/solr create -c XMLTestDataSet

Comment: then go to the core XMLTestDataSet and check if you have the schema.xml...

Comment: no schema.xml but there is managed-schema which I think similar to what you are talking about .. so how to add the fields for the <trans ..> tags that need to be indexed and their attributes to be stored with the number of trans tags different for each file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110898/discussion-between-abhijit-bashetti-and-user1925930).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a lot of mistakes in my configuration files.
The main problem was that I have to use "XPathEntityProcessor" as a processor for the entity of xml files datasource instead of TikaEntityProcessor.
For undetermined length of field like "trans" it is to be added with multiValued="true"
And the uploaded time needed to be in ISO-8601 format even after I added the DateFormatTransformer to the entity.